# How to install Boost/lexical_cast.hpp in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, c++

How can I install boost/lexical_cast.hpp in my Ubuntu-12.04? Does ubuntu 12.04 has default boost package installed? if so, then how can I be able to see which version it is and what libraries are there in this package?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=%20boost/lexical_cast.hpp&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any) the packages `libboost1.46-dev` and `libboost1.48-dev` contain that file.

Click on the package links at the search results to get more information about that packages.

Comment: this is not a direct ans of my question

Comment: versatile and comprehensive answer produces _apt-file_ utility: `apt-file search lexical_cast` say that you must install _libboost1.4[68]-dev_ package